# Do I need to release the COM object on every 'foreach' iteration?

Tags: c#, com, memory-management, memory-leaks, com-interop

Here's the (potential) problem:

I create a COM object, and then use a 'foreach' to iterate through each element in a collection it returns.  Do I need to release each individual element I iterate through in the collection?  (See code below.)  If so, I can't think of a way to effectively to release it from within a 'finally' statement, just in case there is an error as the item is being operated upon.

Any suggestions?

```
private static void doStuff()
{
    ComObjectClass manager = null;

    try
    {
        manager = new ComObjectClass();
        foreach (ComObject item in manager.GetCollectionOfItems())
        {
            Log.Debug(item.Name);
            releaseComObject(item); // <-- Do I need this line?
                                    //     It isn't in a 'finally' block...
                                    //             ...Possible memory leak?
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    finally
    {
        releaseComObject(manager);
    }
}

private static void releaseComObject(object instance)
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance);
        }
        catch
        {
            /* log potential memory leak */
            Log.Debug("Potential memory leak: Unable to release COM object.");
        }
        finally
        {
            instance = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not use a `foreach` statement with a COM object, as a reference is made behind the scenes to which you have no control over releasing. I would switch to a `for` loop and make sure you [never use two dots with COM objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c)

The way this would look would be:

```
try
{
    manager = new ComObjectClass();
    ComObject comObject = null;
    ComObject[] collectionOfComItems = manager.GetCollectionOfItems();
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < collectionOfComItems.Count; i++)
        {
            comObject = collectionOfComItems[i];
            ReleaseComObject(comObject);
        }
    }            
    finally
    {
        ReleaseComObject(comObject);
    }
}
finally 
{
    ReleaseComObject(manager);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's the answer I was looking for, and dreading.

Comment: That would make the whole loop much slower, though.

Comment: @nawfal Why would this make the loop slower?

Comment: Depends on COM object itself, its implementation. When i used to run a for loop for Word and Excel interop automation, I found it much slower than running foreach loop. The indexing may not be really good. Who knows, if its a linear search internally?

Comment: I see; either way, a foreach will cause a memory leak. So even if it is faster up front, it will slow you down later ;-)

Comment: Would it be as good to move the `try`/`finally` inside of the loop and remove the redundant `ReleaseComObject`?  Is there a concern that `collectionOfComItems.Count` would raise an exception?

Comment: @SandyGifford, Looking back at this four years later, I don't recall, but it looks like I was modeling off the OP's try/finally structure. That said, I don't believe it should make a difference, as `collectionOfComItems.Count ` is just operating on an `Array`, not a COM object.

Comment: @MarkAvenius one more question again 3 years later from your last comment, doesn't `collectionOfComItems` variable need a `ReleaseComObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create your own iterator function :

```cs
IEnumerable<ComObject> GetChildItems(this ComObjectClass manager) {
    ComObject comObject = null;

    ComObject[] collectionOfComItems = manager.GetCollectionOfItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < collectionOfComItems.Length; i++) {
        try {
            comObject = collectionOfComItems[i];

            yield return comObject;
        } finally {
            if (comObject != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(comObject);
        }
    }

    yield break;
}

private static void doStuff() {
    ComObjectClass manager = null;

    try {
        manager = new ComObjectClass();

        foreach (ComObject item in manager.GetChildItems()) {
            Log.Debug(item.Name);
        }
    } finally {
        releaseComObject(manager);
    }
}
```

I feel this makes your code much more readable, especially if you need to iterate through the child items at multiple times.